# Failed Installing or running rJava on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: java, environment-variables

I am going to ask myself a question and answer it. I've been bugged by installation of rJava for many time and I finally decided to put all problems in one thread and document that on StackExchange.

1. I have run `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/...` and `echo $JAVA_HOME` shows correct location. But sudo R CMD javareconf report error "invalid JAVA_HOME invalid". What happened?
2. When I run `require(rJava)` in `sudo R`, it gives "can't load libjvm.so" or "xxx file doesn't exist" error, but `require(rJava)` works in `R`.
3. Follows from Q2, `require(rJava)` works in `sudo R` but not in `R`.
4. The output from `echo $JAVA_HOME` or `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` run on Terminal is different from ones run in R with `system("echo $JAVA_HOME")` or `system("echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH)`.
5. Which Java should I install? I had JRE installed but it didn't work.
6. `require(rJava)` works in Terminal R but not RStudio server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Examine your environment settings, I've found that `export JAVA_HOME=xxx` doesn't actually work. Run `cat /etc/environment` and check if the `JAVA_HOME` variable is set to the correct path. Then you have to copy and paste your intended `JAVA_HOME` path and set the `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/environment` to be that one.
2. Check if your `$PATH` variable has `*your_java_home_path*/bin` in it, and if it has *your_ld_library_path* in it. The `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is the one with `libjvm.so` in it. I have no idea what this .so is for, but it has caused me much trouble.
3. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232624/r-package-rjava-only-loads-if-i-launch-r-with-sudo

   Doesn't really helped me because I met Q2, not Q3. But might help you.
4. Solution same as Q2.
5. Install the one from Oracle website http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Don't run `apt-get install xxx`. You thought it's saving your time but you actually got a lot of things you don't actually want.

6. Run `sudo rstudio-server restart`. It is still running the old rsession when you haven't reconfigured your Java yet.

#### What if it still doesn't work?

Completely uninstall your java. Following this thread
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_overview.html

Then reinstall following A5 instructions. Then go to `/etc/environment` to set your path following A1 and A2.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use Oracle's Jre or Jdk rather than Openjdk: Purge all Java related stuff and reinstall via [ppa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Package_Archive) from http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html.

This way you'll receive all (security) updates in exactly the same fashion as regular Ubuntu updates using **apt-get / aptitude update**.